# histogram making used by avx512

Tags: avx512

I tried the first time to make a parallel implementation of histogram using avx512 instructions.
My dataset is an array which contains ints from 0 to 255.( the array is aligned ), so my final histogram array contains 256 int, which should represent the number of pixel of each brightness.
So to implement a parallel solution, i made a 16x larger array( 16 = SIMD_WIDTH in code and this is how many int32 fit in avx512 simd register), to ensure each simd lane do his memory transaction to his own histogram area, to avoid memory conflict, here is the code runing fine.
The problem appears when i tried to sum these local_elements to a final histogram ( in the program local_hists, and global_hist) using avx512. When I sum it, using scalar code, it works well.
So here is my SIMD code:

```
for( int i = 0; i<SIMD_WIDTH; i++){
    for( int j = 0; j < hist_size ; j+=SIMD_WIDTH){
                _mm512_store_epi32( global_hist + j , _mm512_add_epi32( _mm512_load_epi32(global_hist + j) , _mm512_load_epi32(local_hists + (i*hist_size + j*SIMD_WIDTH)) ) );
    }
}
```

And here is my scalar code:

```
    for(int i = 0; i<SIMD_WIDTH; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < hist_size;j++){
                global_hist[j]+=local_hists[i*hist_size + j];
            }
        }
```

hist_size = 256, SIMD_WIDTH = 16 , all array is aligned
The local_hists array is a 16*256 long int array, the first 256 elements represents the first SIMD lane histograms the next 256 elements the second SIMD lane, and so on.

I used gdb to identify the place of problem and i found , that this appears when i sum local_hists, using SIMD.
I tried a scalar code, which working well

Comment: Hard to read what you're actually doing with all those intrinsics on a single line.  What problem?  Also, you could just let the compiler vectorize the scalar code; that should compile efficiently.  Also, you mentioned `long int`, but you're using `epi32` (32-bit) intrinsic elements?  Use a fixed-with type like `uint32_t`, not one that's different between Windows x64 vs. non-Windows x86-64 systems.

Comment: Also, you don't want to *actually* store and reload inside the inner loop, just add into a temporary `__m512i` that you store once at the end.  Compilers reliably do that for scalar code like `global_hist[j] += stuff`, as long as they can sort out the aliasing and be sure `global_hist` doesn't overlap with `local_hists`.  But anyway, with verbose intrinsics code, it's more readable to have a `__m512i sum` temporary. BTW, you don't actually need separate storage, you could just sum into the bottom of `local_hists` and `realloc` (or `std::vector::shrink_to_fit`) to give back the unused space.